# Maximum merged cell content length - Java POI 3.7

Tags: java, merge, cell, apache-poi

I am aware that the maximum length of a single HSSF Workbook cell's content is `32,676` characters. If I merge cells over 3 rows can I get a max length of `3*32676` or does it not work this way?

Comment: Try to run a code that implements this behavior and you will have your answer.

Comment: I have tried a few things to no avail. Hence the post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you'll be able to do that. `HSSF` pretty much implements what the underlying Excel 1997-2003 format supports. That said, in general, trying to merge two or more cells w/ data in them results in some truncation. The truncation is dependent on how the excel is viewed. So, to answer your question, you'll not be able to retain ALL the data across the cells. You would either have data from the upper-left or the upper-right cell retained.